# If I know the password of a WPA2 access point, can I passively eavesdrop to communications?

Tags: security, wifi, wpa

Suppose there's a WPA2 hotspot with a few stations connected to it, and suppose I know the passphrase to connect to this hotspot. Will it be possible to decrypt everyone's communication by being completely passive? (i.e. just sniffing the packets with a wifi sniffer, and without connecting to the network or sending packets to the air).

For this matter, is there a difference between knowing the alphanumeric passphrase or the hexadecimal PSK?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has an answer here http://security.stackexchange.com/q/66421/8340

Comment: no it's unrelated to the Q in the link you mentioned (which was about WPA2-Enterprise). This is about WPA2-personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passphrase is used to generate a PSK via a password hashing function (PBKDF2) which you can easily do yourself, so knowing either the passphrase or the PSK is sufficient.

Between the AP and any particular station, the PSK is used to create a set of temporal keys that are actually used to encrypt frames.

If you capture the 4-way handshake which takes place after authentication/association between the AP and a station, then you will be able to deduce the temporal keys that were calculated for that session, and use these to decrypt unicast frames between the two, and broadcast frames from the AP.

Wireshark will do this for you if you capture the traffic complete with 4 way handshake, and enter the PSK/passphrase.

So to answer your question - yes, you can theoretically passively decrypt traffic if you know the PSK/passhprase without having to actively inject any extra frames, as long as you capture the initial 4-way handshake.

You only need to start injecting frames if you want to force a station to reauthenticate and perform its 4 way handshake, for example by spoofing a deauth.

Comment: perfect answer. Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to configure a hotspot where such eavesdropping would not be possible? For example, each stations uses a temporal key to communicate with the AP, but it is generated via some public-private key-exchange algorithm and therefore cannot be deduced from the passphrase/PSK?

Comment: This is effectively what Wi-Fi Protected Setup (WPS) does - it uses diffie-helman to securely exchange a random passphrase, even when being observed. This passhprase is then used to generate temporal keys via a 4 way handshake as normal.
You may also want to look at 802.11X where an EAP variant can be used to securely share a passphrase between an authentication server and a client, again, this is secure against eavesdropping and tends to be used in corporations and universities etc.

Comment: so with an on-going communication link (ie the target STA is already connected and the 4-way handshake had passed), there is no way to decrypt/eavesdrop that link right? Will something like airpcap help at all in this case?